# React - redux array map

Tags: reactjs

Could some one tell how this image data iterate using array map and assign into the UL LI tag Assume this is the response generated from and I want to populate this data somewhere.

[image]

Comment: This question is quite difficult to answer in its current form; these guidelines may help you to improve your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: read docs, search for 'react render loop'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) to map over the elements.

Example:

```
{
  React.Children.map(your_response_element, (child, i) => {
    return child
  })
}
```